# C# Nest Elasticsearch - Use Context Descriptor To Filter Completion Suggestions by Boolean Field

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using completion suggesters to provide search suggestions as the user types.  I added an `IsActive` property to my C# class, and I cannot figure out how to use that in the `.Suggest.Completion` query.  I know it has something to do with contexts but I cannot find any examples for elasticsearch / nest 6.8.

How do I update my mappings and query to prevent documents with IsActive=false from being suggested?

This is my backing class:

```
[ElasticsearchType(
       IdProperty = "search"
   )]
public class SearchCompletion
{
    public string search { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Use this field for aggregations and sorts
    /// </summary>
    [Keyword]
    public string search_keyword { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// To use for sorting results when searching SearchCompletions 
    /// directly since you can't sort by the Completionfield.Weight 
    /// property for some reason
    /// </summary>
    public int weight { get; set; }

    public CompletionField suggest { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my Mapping Method:**

```
public static void MapSearchCompletions(ElasticClient client, string index)
{
    var mapResponse = client.Map<SearchCompletion>(m => m
        .Index(index)
        .AutoMap()


        //  WHAT GOES HERE??
        .Properties(props => props
            .Completion(c => c
                .Name(n => n.isActive)  
                .Contexts(context => context
                    .Category(cat => cat.Name("isActive"))
                )
            )
        )         
    ); //re-apply the index mapping
}
```

**This is My Query**

```
var response = client.Search<SearchCompletion>(s => s
    .Index(suggest_index)
    .Suggest(su => su
        .Completion("search", cs => cs
            .Field(f => f.suggest)
            .Contexts(con => con.Context("")) //  WHAT GOES HERE??
            .Prefix(search)
            .Size(size)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `boolean` as a `category` value. I haven't tried that in ES but NEST is accepting string for `category` type. So, I suggest you to update your mappings.
*(I'm updating it to `string` to continue)*
Looks like you are creating index at some other place. Your code is just creating mappings. It could be as:

```
        var mapResponse = client.Map<SearchCompletion>(m => m
            .Index("index")
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(props => props
                .Completion(c => c
                    .Name(n => n.suggest)
                    .Contexts(context => context
                        .Category(cat => cat.Name("isActive"))
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        // let's create data
        var r1 = client.Index(new SearchCompletion
        {
            search = "plate", suggest = new CompletionField
            {
                Input = new[] {"plate", "dish"}, // this one has two suggestions
                Contexts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    {
                        "isActive",
                        new[] {"yes"} // isActive is 'yes'
                    }
                }
            }
        }, d => d.Index("index"));

        var r2 = client.Index(new SearchCompletion
        {
            search = "fork",
            suggest = new CompletionField
            {
                Input = new[] { "fork", "dis_example" }, // this has two suggestions
                Contexts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    {
                        "isActive",
                        new[] {"no"} // isActive is 'no'
                    }
                }
            }
        }, d => d.Index("index"));

        var r3 = client.Index(new SearchCompletion
        {
            search = "spoon",
            suggest = new CompletionField
            {
                Input = new[] { "spoon" },
                Contexts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    {
                        "isActive",
                        new[] {"yes"} // isActive is 'yes'
                    }
                }
            }
        }, d => d.Index("index"));

        // Let's search for the dish using 'dis' and limiting it to IsActive == 'yes'
        var searchResponse = client.Search<SearchCompletion>(s => s.Index("index").Suggest(su => su
            .Completion("search", cs => cs
                .Field(f => f.suggest)
                .Contexts(con => con.Context("isActive", aa => aa.Context("yes")))
                .Prefix("dis")
                .Size(10)
            )
        ));
```

And indeed we are getting plate suggestion:

```
{
...
  "suggest" : {
    "search" : [
      {
        "text" : "dis",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 3,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "dish",
            "_index" : "testindex",
            "_type" : "searchcompletion",
            "_id" : "plate",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "search" : "plate",
              "weight" : 0,
              "suggest" : {
                "input" : [
                  "plate",
                  "dish"
                ],
                "contexts" : {
                  "isActive" : [
                    "yes"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "contexts" : {
              "isActive" : [
                "yes"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```